# How to apply refinements / monkey-patches globally via environment.rb?

Tags: ruby, monkeypatching

Lets take the example from the [Rainbow gem](https://github.com/sickill/rainbow):

`using Rainbow` allows to color string objects directly like so `'Hi'.green`.

However, when I tried to add `using Rainbow` to `environment.rb` in the hopes of being able to access the monkey-patched coloring methods in any file the `environment.rb` is required in, seems like the coloring methods are not available.

Is there a way to apply the monkey-patch globally once instead of doing `using Rainbow` in each file separately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

That is *literally* the whole point of Refinements. If that were possible, Refinements would be *fundamentally b0rken*.

Refinements are *only* active in the lexical scope they are `use`d in.